# What sorts of fish were Sharky and George

Tags: character, sharky-and-george

The early 90s Kids TV show Sharky and George featured two fish detectives in a 1930s style ganster fish town. The basic premise is covered here on Wikipedia [Sharky And George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharky_%26_George)

[image]

But what kinds of fish were Sharky and George supposed to be?
Sharky is reasonably obviously a Shark, but all the listings I can find (wikipedia, imdb etc.) just describe George as a Blue and Orange or Blue and Yellow fish. Was he supposed to be a particular species?

I'm trying to figure out if George is supposed to be a pilot fish. This would bring a second layer to relationship between Sharky and George. It would give a backstory by species reason for George to be the driving force of the partnership and Sharky to be more passive despite his larger size. I'm hoping to find out if this is intended or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find any canon information about what George is, but his "hairy" dorsal fin reminds me this fish from *Finding Nemo*:

[image: Tad fish from Finding Nemo]

Which is a Butterfly Fish. The colors are similar but inverted:

[image: Butterfly fish]

It also has a long pointy *nose*, like George.

Comment: I think this is about as close as we're ever going to get. It's not the exciting nuanced solution I was hoping for, but sometimes things just happen without good reasons.